# Does $n^A\cong n^B \Rightarrow A\approx B$ require choice?

Tags: vector-spaces, axiom-of-choice

Let $V$ be a vector space over a *finite field* $F$.

Assume $V$ has a basis $S$.
Then, define $\Phi:V^*\rightarrow F^S:f\mapsto f\upharpoonright S$. It can be shown that $\Phi$ is an isomorphism. Thus, $V^*\cong F^S$. Thus if $S'$ is another basis for $V$, then $F^S\cong F^{S'}$. Does this imply $S\approx S'$ in ZF?

Comment: There are two interpretations of the question. A) If $F^S \cong F^{S'}$, do we have $S \cong S'$? B) If $S,S'$ are bases of a vector space, do we have $S \cong S'$? Asaf has answered both, I think.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't even imply $S\approx S'$ in ZFC.

Suppose that $2^{\aleph_0}=2^{\aleph_1}=\aleph_2$. Consider now $S=\omega$ and $S'=\omega_1$. Both have duals of *cardinality* $\aleph_2$, and since the cardinality of a vector space is the $\max\{|F|,\dim V\}$, since $F$ is finite it has to be that both these duals have the same dimension: $\aleph_2$. Therefore they are isomorphic.

In the context of ZF, it is consistent to have a vector space with two bases of distinct cardinality.

Comment: Did you mean "in the context of ZF"?

Comment: @Trevor: No, I meant in the context of vector spaces, $F^S$ and $F^{S'}$ are vector spaces when $F$ is a field.

Comment: Well, the whole question is about vector spaces, so I just thought your second sentence would make more sense if it said "in the context of ZF" to contrast with the "in ZFC" in the first sentence.  So I thought maybe it was a typo.  Can't say it's wrong as is, though.

Comment: @Trevor: Suppose $2^{\aleph_0}=2^{\aleph_1}=\aleph_2$. Now take the dual of $2^\Bbb Q$ and $2^\Bbb R$. Both have size $\aleph_2$. Therefore they have bases of size $\aleph_2$. Therefore they are isomorphic. But obviously $\Bbb Q$ and $\Bbb R$ have different sizes. All this within the confines of ZFC.

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean now.  I still contend that the whole question is in the context of vector spaces though :)

Comment: @Trevor: And that's the drawback of little to no sleep! :-)

Comment: Sorry, I'm confused again.  Regardless of the stuff about duals, isn't the question just asking whether the cardinality of a basis of a given vector space is unique?  So now I don't understand your _first_ sentence.  (Note that $F^S$ and $F^{S'}$ are assumed to be isomorphic, not just equinumerous.)

Comment: @Trevor: The cardinality of an infinitely dimensional vector space over a finite field is the cardinality of its basis. Since the two vector spaces have *size* $\aleph_2$ their bases must be of size $\aleph_2$. Equinumerous bases, well... you know the rest.

Comment: Oops, I was misreading the question the whole time.  Now it is my turn to get some sleep.